# Iterate through multiple class using find_element_by_class_name in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Selenium webdriver in Python for a web-scraping project.

The webpage, I am working on has a number of Table entries with the same class name.

```
<table class="table1 text print">
```

I am using `find_element_by_class_name`. However I am getting a error :

**`Compound class names not permitted` **

Another question:

How to iterate through all the tables having the same css classname ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `find_elements_by_class_name`. This will return an iterable object.

Answer (score 1):

The error you describe happens when you provide multiple class names rather than a single one.  An easy way around this is to get the elements using CSSSelector or XPath.  Alternatively, you could use find_elements_by_class_name and provide one class name, then iterate through that list to find the elements that match the additional class names you want to match on as well.